# Elasticsearch: Query only specific documents within an index based on time (first and last)

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I have an index with around 400 milllion documents stored.
The fields in general look like this: systemname, filename, timestamp, message, version, etc,

What I want to get is the first and last document (based on the timestamp) per filename.

What I am doing right now is:

Query the whole index
Define window based on filename
Sort ascending
Add rownumber
Add max_rownumber
Filter all entries where rownumber = 1 or rownumber = max_rownumber
This is really really slow

Code can be seen here: [Getting first and last entry of window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671378/getting-first-and-last-entry-of-window)

ES Version: 6.0.0
ES Spark Connector: elasticsearch-spark-20 6.0.0
Scala Version 2.11.8
Spark Version: 2.2

Does someone have any idea on how I could speed this up?
The best way would probably be to make the I/O smaller but elasticsearch does not feature aggregations with spark. I also found no way to query only specific fields of a document. For this example querying only 5 out of the 10 fields per document would be enough.
 This calculation is taking over 15 hours on a cluster with 112 cores.

If someone could help me with a solution that would be really nice. I am out of Options / Ideas.
Not being able to query aggregations seems to become a dealbreaker for elasticsearch but I don't want to switch away.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169612/elasticsearch-get-docs-with-max-and-min-timestamp-values

Comment: @NilsH This is not really a duplicate since this question only refers to elasticsearch where you can use aggregations. Like I wrote in this question the spark-elastic connection does not provide aggregations. What I am looking for is another way to accomplish this result.

Comment: Apologies. I missed that part. And I am also surprised that ES spark does not have that option...

Comment: Sad but true :( Seems like I will not be using elasticsearch for long.